# QTextBrowser doesn't properly show backslashed characters

Tags: python, xml, pyqt, pyqt5, qbytearray

I'm creating a widget that will display XML strings in a pretty formatted way. To do this I'm using a `QXmlStreamReader` and a `QXmlStreamWriter` (based on the answer from [Format XML file in c++ or Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946734/format-xml-file-in-c-or-qt)) and feed the text to a `QTextBrowser`:

```
message = "<person><name>John</name><surname>Smith</surname><hobbies><sport>football</sport><sport>tenis</sport><activity>dancing</activity></hobbies></person>"
byteArray = QByteArray()
xmlReader = QXmlStreamReader(message)
xmlWriter = QXmlStreamWriter(byteArray)
xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(True)
while (not xmlReader.atEnd()):
    xmlReader.readNext();
    if (not xmlReader.isWhitespace()):
        xmlWriter.writeCurrentToken(xmlReader)
prettyMessage = str(byteArray.data())
textBrowser.setText(prettyMessage)
```

But the resulting text doesn't convert `\n` to new lines:

[image]

If I input manually a string with `\n` in it, they are converted to new lines:

```
textBrowser.setText("1\n2\n3\n4")
```

[image]

I've checked the exact content of `byteArray` to make sure that the `\n` is passed as one character and not as two separate '\' and 'n' characters:

```
for i in range(0, byteArray.size()):
    sys.stdout.write(byteArray.at(i))
```

prints out the XML string as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <hobbies>
        <sport>football</sport>
        <sport>tenis</sport>
        <activity>dancing</activity>
    </hobbies>
</person>
```

---

<sup>I'm using python 3.6 with PyQt5</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the data in the `QByteArray`. This can be done using a `QTextStream`, which then allows you to easily set the right codec:

```
    byteArray = QByteArray()
    xmlReader = QXmlStreamReader(message)
    xmlWriter = QXmlStreamWriter(byteArray)
    xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(True)
    while (not xmlReader.atEnd()):
        xmlReader.readNext();
        if (not xmlReader.isWhitespace()):
            xmlWriter.writeCurrentToken(xmlReader)

    stream = QTextStream(byteArray)
    stream.setCodec(xmlWriter.codec())
    textBrowser.setText(stream.readAll())
```

Comment: The line `stream.setCodec(xmlWriter.codec())` is not necesary.

Comment: @SIMEL. It is necessary if the xml writer uses a codec that is different to the default used by `QTextStream`. So it is generally better to always include that line.